# Traces below micro-USB power

Tags: pi-3b+

If I were to drill through the micro-USB power port on a raspberry pi 3 b+, would I drill through any important traces on the board?

Concept Image below
[image: What I would theoretically do]

Comment: you would probably drill through the ground plane, which is important ... are you asking if you would cut traces? ... drill where? ... what size drill?

Comment: Why would you want or need to do this?

Comment: Added concept Image